# Strange HDD sound with sytem hanging

Tags: hard-drive, pata

I have an old computer with three IDE (PATA) hard drives. Sometimes (I still don't know what's causing it) some of them suddenly clicks, creaks and squeaks, system hangs for a second and then continues to run normally (when computer boots the sound is similar but happens only once). I already tried to use only one HDD. It doesn't happen often but I'm worried about losing data. Could it be because of my HDDs are old (maybe they should rest already)? What should I do?

Comment: worry about data. find somebody that can make an image / do it yourself, quick. But carefully. Don't overuse the drive. It could be on its last legs re clicking.

Comment: All the behavior you describe, indicates the hardware is failing, replace the drives as quickly as possible.  If you are worried about data you should have backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the data on this drive **DO NOT** continue to use the drive. The longer you use a failing drive the worse and more unreliable it becomes.

I think a good place to start with is a drive test. There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives and often times there will be built in diagnostics as well you can use. One simple but effective tool I like to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/downloads/legacy-downloads#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

If DFT reports that the drive is failing (diagnostics in red box) you should try to backup your data immediately.

Comment: i did what you said and heard one of those noises again while performing `advanced test`. strange but `drive fitnes test` shown me `green screen` with `disposition code 0x00` (i was expecting red however). could the problem be with IDE controller on m/b?

Comment: From the sound of the problem, it doesn't sound like the IDE controller would be an issue.  The drive may just be showing its age if it making strange sounds.  Best advice I can give for now would be to back everything up, continue using the drive and just carefully monitor the drive going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Hanging can be an issue of the clogged operating system.

Also, if some strange clicks/sounds of an HDD appear, this is a bad sign. I commend you to check its S.M.A.R.T. status at first.

Comment: i used `wmic` command with `diskdrive get status` parameter which shown OK. `CrystalDiskInfo` also shown `good condition` for all of three drives.

Comment: If you value your data, move it to a new good HDD and keep using the old one for unimportant tasks.

Comment: yes i will but what could possibly cause such an issue? it happens rarely and is spontaneous.

Comment: I believe it can be an issue of head's positioning.